# extracting specific data from text file in c#

Tags: c#, file

I have a .txt file in my project which has the following contents:

```
Mode: 1
Number of candidates: 64
serial number: 111111101
room number: 111111111
score_1: 0
score_2: 0
Total: 0
```

I read all the lines and store it in an array using the following.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("file.txt", Encoding.UTF8);
```

I want to extract only the values of each line, e.g. for the line with the "room number", I want to extract only `"111111111"` without the space and print it on console and save it in a variable. How do I do that using C#?

Comment: Use string methods: Split and Trim

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `Substring` and `IndexOf`?

```
 string[] values = lines
   .Select(line => line.Substring(line.IndexOf(':') + 1).TrimLeft())
   .ToArray();
```

If you want to *preserve names* (e.g. `Mode`, `score_2` etc.) try `Split`:

```
 KeyValuePair<string, string>[] data = lines
   .Select(line => line.Split(new char[] {':'}, 2))
   .Where(items => items.Length >= 2) // let's filter out lines without colon
   .Select(items => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(items[0], items[1].TrimLeft()))
   .ToArray();
```

Comment: I don't really like the generalized *avoid `ReadAllLines `*. It has its use for a not-so-big file where all content will be used anyway. Regarding your second code block, I suggest `Split(new char[] { ':' }, 2)` if there is any value that's not a number (and may contain `':'`)

Comment: @grek40: I totally agree with the suggestion (I've edited the answer): in general case `Split(new char[] { ':' }, 2)` is more efficient than simple `Split( ':')`. `ReadAllLines` is an antipattern in the constructions like `ReadAllLines(...). ... .ToArray()`. If we split the logic into `string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines()` and then `values = lines. ... .ToArray()` as in the edited question, `ReadAllLines` is OK.